# Is it possible for one app to check for how long any other app was running on iphone/ipad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7, monitoring

I want to monitor for how long the apps were being run in the foreground and want to keep some statistics.

Lets assume that I have Apps A,B,C,D on my iphone/ipad and I install one more app "MyMonitoringApp" I want to get the details about how long A,B,C,D were used or run in the foreground from MyMonitoringApp and want to take some action if they exceed certain limit. Is there a way to do this programatically?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This can't be done using any public APIs.

Comment: If apps A-D are your own apps, you can give your monitoring app a custom URL scheme that those other apps will invoke as they start and finish. But if A-D are not your apps, then, no, there is no API to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible. At most, you can check if another app is installed if you know its URL Scheme. Anything more than that is not possible.